# How do I use databinder.eval on extended properties in a datatable?

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have a datacolumn with an extended property that I want to show in a datagrid.
In code I can reference it this way:

```
 bool show = bool.parse(myDataTable.Columns["Price"].ExtendedProperties["Visible"].ToString());
```

In my repeater, I have this

```
            <ItemTemplate>

             $<%#Eval("Price") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

What can I put inside an eval statement to show the 'Visible' extended property?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried 
Eval("Price.Visible") ?

Comment: I get an error:
 DataBinding: 'System.Single' does not contain a property with the name 'Visible'.